# How do you get only XML elements and not whitespace with the javascript DOMParser?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

So, I am trying to parse XML with javascript, but when I do this, any whitespace, likes spaces or newlines causes unwanted nodes in the resulting DOM or XMLDocument object:

```js
//xml parsing example

var xp = new DOMParser();

var test = "<program><event><i>6</i></event></program>";

var xenon = xp.parseFromString(test, "text/xml");

console.log(xenon.childNodes[0].childNodes.length);
//prints 1 

//adding newlines
test = "<program>\n<event>\n<i>6</i></event></program>";

xenon = xp.parseFromString(test, "text/xml");

console.log(xenon.childNodes[0].childNodes.length);
//prints 2
```

How do I parse the xml so that only elements, and not any whitespace are included as child nodes? I have looked up a "clean" method, but there should be a parser option for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No There is no parse option. The parsing procedure sees that `'\n'` should be text nodes so it creates them as text nodes. What you need to do is that after the parsing, ignore those text node. [**childNodes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode) selects all the children including the text nodes ones, use [**children**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead. `children` return only element children. Or use `querySelectorAll` like this:

```
var elems = xenon.querySelectorAll("program > *");
console.log(elems.length); // outputs 1
```